# Weird mystery : index.php not accessible on a specific server, with a specific OS

Tags: javascript, php, html, http

I have a problem that I have been struggling with for some time.
Initial problem: when I try to access the very simple index.php file here http://pierremaurel.free.fr/ on Chrome (fresh reinstall, up-to-date, safe mode or not) on macOS (up-to-date) I have a blank page.
The code of the index.php file is

```
<html>  
    <body>
        Hello!
    </body>
</html>
```

and the Chrome console tells me:  `GET http://pierremaurel.free.fr/index.php net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED 200 (OK)`

But

- if I rename index.php in index.html: it works
- if I use firefox instead of chrome: it works
- if I use another computer (on windows) or a phone (iOS): it works, regardless of the browser
- if I put the exact same index.php file here https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/pierre.maurel/test2/ (or if I test locally with MampServer) : it works, regardless of the OS and the browser

Furthermore, I also tested some javascript/AJAX here: http://pierremaurel.free.fr/test/ (JS here http://pierremaurel.free.fr/test/test.js, where I try to open a PHP file and an HTML file).

- again, seems to work perfectly fine locally on my mac, on the windows computer, and on my phone
- on macOS, this time, no difference between browsers: the HTML file is well open but the PHP one fails. My window.alert displays the following for the PHP

```
[PHP] state=2 status=200
[PHP] state=3 status=200
[PHP] state=4 status=0
```

- again, the exact same code here https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/pierre.maurel/test/ works perfectly well, even on my MACOS (chrome/firefox/safari)

Today I asked a colleague of mine, also on macOS to test http://pierremaurel.free.fr/ and http://pierremaurel.free.fr/test/ and she had the exact same behavior as myself.

I am completely lost ... does anybody have any lead? any direction to look at?

Comment: It seems is not a problem about yor code or server configuration. Maybe, is a security question under apple consideration. Something like that DNS is blacklisted? I don't know, but it seems something like that

Comment: Try to deactivate firewall in your mac

Comment: thanks for your reply : I tried to deactivate  the firewall, it didn't change a thing ...
 if the DNS was blacklisted, I couldnt access at all to the website, am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

### 4 Things to try:

1. Try to reset cookies, data and all cache of that website.
2. If this does not work then you have to try to open in incognito window.
3. Try to restart your browser.
4. Wait for 72 hours and then try again.

The most probable reason why this sort of thing would happen is that when you must have opened it for the first time, it may not have been activated and would have left some cookies telling browser that the site was not loaded. But now even after it has loaded, the cookies may still be there which may be telling the browser that the site is not loaded and may be preventing the browser from connecting to it. The reason why this is working in firefox is that in firefox you must have opened after it had been activated, so those cookies won't be there.

Comment: thanks for you reply, I allready did all that and the problem is lasting for more than 72 hours. It is also present on an other macbook.

Comment: nobody has an other idea ? or do you know where I could post my problem otherwise ? thanks